# Get pod name and ip from Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a SpringBoot application, dockerized, and deployed in a kubernetes cluster.
There is any way to log the pod name and pod ip from the springboot application inside the container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "pod name and pod ip from the springboot application inside the container" ...this... is a problem. You are starting to pet cattle here

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to run a Fluentd agent on each cluster node.  The agent collects all pod sysouts, decorates the logs with pod attributes and pipes them into ElasticSearch or some other searchable store.  ala [kubernetes-fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using downwardAPI to capture pod name and pod ip as environment variables inside container